python script runs in wordpress
I create simple plugin for wordpress to run python script and display in post.
Python script using websocket to collect live data, constantly runs
problem is when open the page keep loading due to php I think I'm not good with php :)
so how can i get wordress page to display live data from python.
php code
function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'run.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );


if Python gets live data then it can work forever - and PHP may never end.. Maybe better run Python as separate process and collect data in database or queue, and PHP should periodically get only part of data (not all). But this makes problem to run PHP periodically and update page. It is job rather for JavaScript directly on page in web browser. It could periodically get data directly from Python - but it could also run websocket  and get data directly from page with live data.

I was using flask  for visual , would be nice to see wordpress do visual with python. seem like only option is javascript
